# Setting UIControl's frame changes view bounds but not where it can receive touches

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uicontrol, cgrect

I have a `headerView` which can expand and collapse when pressed. It's default state is collapsed.

I use the following code to expand the `headerView`.

```
if (!self.headerViewIsExpanded) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [self.collapsedHeaderView removeFromSuperview];
    self.headerView.frame = self.expandedHeaderView.frame;
    [self.headerView addSubview:self.expandedHeaderView];

    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y + offset, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height - offset);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.headerViewIsExpanded = YES;
}
```

It correctly expands the view frame and diminishes the tableView frame. However, it fails to expand the touches received area of the original UIControl, so I can only collapse it by pressing where the original frame was.

How can I resolve this issue?

EDIT: Alternatively, I would accept an answer with a good explanation of why I cannot resolve the issue, or at least not resolve it safely.

EDIT 1: To be more clear, the `headerView` is NOT a `tableView` header view. It is just a view that sits on top of the table that happens to be called `headerView`. Both `headerView` and `tableView` are subviews of the main `UIView` that spans the available window.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to overload **layoutSubviews** method. Inside you should use setFrame method for your headerView to define all view elements position.

Comment: Why would I need to override `layoutSubviews`? Isn't this verbotten?

Comment: This method is called when UIView calls `- (void)layoutIfNeeded`, according to redefine subviews positions during some events. For ex, I am using this method for placing standart textLabel inside UITableView cell in different frame and adding additional UITableView inside cell... But I think you can get same effect if you use heightForHeaderInSection method after tableView reloadData.

Comment: I should have made it more clear... `headerView` exists outside of the `tableView`. It is just a regular old `UIControl` that happens to be called `headerView`. The tableView has no `headerForSection:` defined. This is really just a question about `UIControl`.

Comment: Oh that was misunderstanding. Unfortunately I have nothing to say about your issue, because I have not faces problem like this before.